# Saving Configuration Section Error - Elements are merged as attributes

Tags: asp.net, configuration-files, configurationsection

I have created a configuration section designer project to represent nodes of a custom section necessary to read and save from my web application.  I am able to successfully create instances of the configuration elements and collections, however when I save the configuration using the referenced `System.Configuration.Configuration` object and issuing `save`, the elements get merged into their parents as attributes.  An example of the issue is outlined below:

After calling the referenced Configuration.save, the output is as follows:

```
  <savedReports xmlns="SavedReportSchema.xsd">
      <resultsSets dataViewId="1" id="4203bb88-b0c4-4d57-8708-18e48f0a1d2d">
          <selects keyId="1" sortOrder="1" />
      </resultsSets>
  </savedReports>
```

As defined in my configuration section designer project (confirmed by the resulting xsd as well) the output should match the following:

```
<savedReports xmlns="SavedReportSchema.xsd">
  <resultsSets>
    <savedReport id="1">
      <selects>
        <select keyId="1" sortOrder="1"/>
      </selects>
    </savedReport>
  </resultsSets>
</savedReports>
```

Any ideas?  The element collection types are set to `BasicMapAlternate` however when I set them to `AddRemoveClearMapAlternate` they are not merged but they are prefixed by "add" rather than "select" or "savedReport" causing the validation to be off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `AddRemoveClearMapAlternate` was the option I needed to correct my problem referenced in the question.